# SQL group by for aggregate with sorted input?

Tags: sql, sorting, group-by, aggregate, sql-order-by

This is a question about SQL (the standard) as much as about PostgreSQL.

If we have an aggregate function that depends on the order of applying it, such as, for example, some concatenate aggregator (in PgSQL there is string_agg, or array_agg) and in Oracle there is list_agg or something, then the order that the rows are fed into the aggregation matters.

It would seem that the SQL standard for that should have some sort of GROUP BY ... ORDERED BY ... clause as fictitiously written like this:

```
SELECT groupKey,
       string_agg(col, '; ') AS col
  FROM Tab
  GROUP BY groupKey ORDERING BY sortKey
```

which ORDERING BY is different from the normal ORDER BY clause which sorts the result of the group aggregate operation. But that doesn't exist (and ChatGPT also has no idea how to do this directly.

We can use the window mode of calling the aggregator with

```
WITH ExcessiveAggregateWorkProduct AS (
  SELECT groupKey,
         row_number() OVER w AS rownum,
         string_agg(col, '; ') OVER w AS col
    FROM Tab
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY groupKey ORDER BY sortKey
                   ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
) SELECT * FROM ExcessiveAggregateWorkProduct 
   WHERE rownum = 1
```

But this is expensive because that window aggregate needs to be computed for every row only to throw away all but the first.

So I often just do this:

```
WITH SortedTab AS (
  SELECT groupKey, col
    FROM Tab
    ORDER BY groupKey, sortKey
) SELECT groupKey,
         string_agg(col, '; ') AS col
    FROM SortedTab
    GROUP BY groupKey;
```

and usually the query plan tells me that it should work. But there is no guarantee.

I would like to know how it can be guaranteed or how that excessive aggregation could be limited up front or how the RDBMS engine is supposed to optimize that away?

Comment: add a limit/TOP to the WITH, return sets like tables are unsorted by nature, that is why ordering the WITH is a unnecessary, but adding a LIMIT/ TOP changes that

Comment: but when i think about it, all rdms have a aggegation function for strings, with always include an ORDER BY

Comment: @nbk I think that order by clause in the aggregate is the answer.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question (maybe updating it with sample data would help) but if you are trying to set the order in which values are aggregated together using, for example, list_agg then that function has an optional ORDER BY clause that does this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is

```
SELECT groupKey,
       string_agg(col, '; ' ORDER BY sortKey) AS col
  FROM Tab
  GROUP BY groupKey
```

Even ChatGPT didn't know that ;)

The interesting thing is, in PostgreSQL where CREATE AGGREGATE is totally easy, you do not need to specify anything special to allow such order by to work. For example:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE tsvector_agg(
  sfunc = tsvector_concat, 
  basetype = tsvector, 
  stype = tsvector
);
```

and immediately you can use `tsvector_agg(... ORDER BY sortKey)`

Comment: *Even ChatGPT didn't know that* - tbh ChatGPT for code-based questions is very much hit-and-miss, it can only reguritates the crap that's already out there, it's not "AI" in any sense of the word.

Comment: I seem to have haters with all the down-votes. :D